# In Scala, can internal methods be overwritten in subclasses?

Tags: scala

For example in the following

```
class Base {

  def test() {
    def internal() {
      println("base internal")
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible for internal to be overwritten in a subclass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Internal methods are effectively private.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the [answer of Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211645/in-scala-can-internal-methods-be-overwritten-in-subclasses/7211856#7211856): if you want to be able to override the `internal` method, you should declare it as `protected` directly below the `Base` class.

In fact, internal method can be seen as a block of the method itself.